# how to get current streak in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query for getting the current streak in MySQL based on status

| ID | Dated | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-08 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-03-09 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-03-10 | 0 |
| 4 | 2022-03-11 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-03-12 | 0 |
| 6 | 2022-03-13 | 1 |
| 7 | 2022-03-14 | 1 |
| 8 | 2022-03-16 | 1 |
| 9 | 2022-03-18 | 0 |
| 10 | 2022-03-19 | 1 |
| 11 | 2022-03-20 | 1 |

In the above table current streak should be 2( i.e 2022-03-20 - 2022-03-19) based on status 1. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUM(Status) OVER (ORDER BY Dated DESC) s1,
           SUM(NOT Status) OVER (ORDER BY Dated DESC) s2
    FROM table
)
SELECT MAX(s1)
FROM cte
WHERE NOT s2;
```

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(CASE WHEN Status THEN Dated END), 
                MAX(CASE WHEN NOT Status THEN Dated END))
FROM table
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. It's work what if we have the current date is "2022-03-21" I have not done the task of that day it's status will be 0. but I still want to get the current streak 2. When the current day task will be done then it's should show current streak 3 i.e from the current date(2022-03-21) - 2022-03-19. I hope you got my point. Currently, it shows -1 if the current date status will be 0.

Comment: @BasitSatti Your task was not completely defined, so my solution is partial too. The most general solution can be found in Tim Biegeleisen's answer. Also you have not told what is your MySQl version, does it is 8+ or 5.x only (or maybe MariaDB even?).

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  In your case, you want the island of status 1 records which occurs last.  We can use the difference in row numbers method, assuming you are using MySQL 8+.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dated) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY Dated) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rn1 - rn2 DESC) rnk
    FROM cte
    WHERE Status = 1
)

SELECT ID, Dated, Status
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY Dated;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

We can use 2 one row CTE's to find the latest date where the status was not the same as the latest one and then count the records superieur.

```
**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

    create table t(
      ID int,
      Dated date,
      Status int);
    insert into t values
    (1,'2022-03-08',1),
    (2,'2022-03-09',1),
    (3,'2022-03-10',0),
    (4,'2022-03-11',1),
    (5,'2022-03-12',0),
    (6,'2022-03-13',1),
    (7,'2022-03-14',1),
    (8,'2022-03-16',1),
    (9,'2022-03-18',0),
    (10,'2022-03-19',1),
    (11,'2022-03-20',1);

---

**Query #1**

    with latest AS
    (SELECT
        dated lastDate,
        status lastStatus
     from t
     order by dated desc
     limit 1 ),
     lastDiff as
     (select MAX(dated) diffDate
     from t,latest
     where not status = lastStatus
     )
    select count(*) 
    from t ,lastDiff
    where dated > diffDate;

| count(*) |
| -------- |
| 2        |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)
```

We could also consider using `datediff()` to find the number of days that the streak has lasted which might be more interesting than `count()` seeing as there are some days where there is no record.